# state of parallelism in MS C# and Mono

Tags: c#, mono, pthreads, openmp, parallel-processing

for a project I'm working on, I need to work with threads. I was wondering: what is the state of parallelism in MS `C#` and, particularly, `Mono`, as compared for example to `OpenMP` and `pthreads`? How much control do I have over threads in C#? What will I **not** be able to do? For instance, can I synchronize explicitly? Can I work directly with mutexes? Can I do conditional wait?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you will more likely get an answer, if you tell us, what *special things*  OpenMP and pthreads can do. Threading in .NET supports all the default things you can do with threads.

Comment: Threads and parallelism are not the same thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have virtually all the control over threads

The .NET framework contains virtually all (`monitor`, `manualresetevent`, `autoresetevent`, `sempaphore`, `readerwriterlock` etc) primitives. For special needs catering you can always P/Invoke (though you'll have to have multiple implementations to stay portable)

Mono has a PLINQ implementation (coming along)

See Miguel de Icaza's blog post on [C# 3.0 and Parallel FX/LINQ in Mono](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Jul-26-1.html).
It <strike>should be</strike>**is** in [Mono 2.8](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8)

So yes yes yes and yes :)

Answer (score 0):

On mono you can treat your threaded program in exactly the same way as you would on .Net, runtime compatibility of managed code is the main goal of the mono project.